# Pessoa Fisica e Juridica

Tags: java, modelagem, modelo-relacional

Eu tenho um campo que pode receber a pessoa fisica ou juridica, como vcs modelam isto ? atraves de interface, composição ou herança ?

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura de classes:
Contatos (apenas PF) -- pertence a uma --> Empresa (apenas PJ)
Os contatos possuem diversos papeis, como por exemplo: Vendedor, Proprietario, etc

```
public class Contato {
  private Empresa empresa;
  /* ... */
}

public class Empresa {
  private Set<Contato> contatos;
  /* ... */
}
```

Porém eu tb tenho a seguinte situação

```
public class MeuObjeto {
  ??? responsavel;
}
```

nestes casos o responsavel pode ser um *Contato* (Fisica) ou uma *Empresa* (Juridica). não gostaria de cair na solução de Pessoa -> Pessoa Fisica, Pessoa -> Pessoa Juridica, Pensei sobre usar uma interface, mas ela pode acabar crescendo demais. A dúvida é alguem conhece mais algum padrão que pode ajudar na modelagem logica desta situação?

** melhorando a pergunta

Comment: Você fala em classes, no BD ou em ambos? Eu usaria herança ou composição, dependendo do que mais eu quisesse guardar de informação, mas não tenho uma resposta definitiva, acho que analisaria caso a caso...

Comment: Olha Macedo aqui nós não damos opiniões, não falamos o que fazemos, porque isto não vai te ajudar de fato. Damos respostas objetivas que realmente possam ajudar você e outras pessoas. Tente modificar sua resposta colocando mais detalhes do que está fazendo, se está tendo algum problema, enfim tente deixar a pergunta mais objetiva. Desenvolva mais o que está pensando em fazer com estas formas que você listou, e dá para salvar a pergunta. Mas já adianto, cada caso vai ser diferente. Então tente mostrar bem qual é o seu caso.